# Swift: can I use async/await syntax with a function that already returns synchronously a value?

Tags: swift, async-await

I know that I can use async/await to replace this :

```
func test(_ completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    // ...
    completion(foundValue)
}
```

with this:

```
func test async -> Int {
    let result = await calculate()
    return result
}
```

However, can I do something if the initial function is like this?

```
func test(_ completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) -> Int {
    // ...
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't think it is possible for an async function to return something synchronously. Though you could have it return both values asynchronously, as a tuple.

Comment: What is the (practical) purpose of this function?

Comment: If your intent was to support both the `async` rendition and the completion handler pattern (i.e., if you are slowly transitioning codebase to Swift concurrency), you would generally just kept the both of the two renditions in your codebase until the migration is done. One would not have a single method that attempts to do both patterns by itself. See WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/) for some useful migration practices (e.g., automated refactoring, deprecation designations, etc.).

Answer (score -3):

If your function doesn't need to wait for completion handler call then you can create a top level task and call your completion handler from the task after doing asynchronous work:

```swift
func test(_ completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) -> Int {
    // synhronous calls
    Task {
        // async funtion calls
        completion(value)
    }
    return value
}
```

If you need to wait for all your asynchronous task completion before returning, you can use a semaphore for that:

```
func test(_ completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) -> Int {
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    // synhronous calls
    Task {
        // async funtion calls
        completion(value)
        // signal async task completion
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    // wait for async task completion
    semaphore.wait()
    return value
}
```

Or, you can wrap your asynchronous task inside an [operation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) like [here](https://github.com/SwiftyLab/AsyncObjects/blob/main/Sources/AsyncObjects/TaskOperation.swift). You can signal the operation finish once the underlying async task finishes and wait for operation completion using [`waitUntilFinished()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1409256-waituntilfinished):

```swift
let op = TaskOperation {
   try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
}
op.waitUntilFinished()
```

Note that using `semaphore.wait()` or `op.waitUntilFinished()` blocks the current thread and blocking the thread can cause undefined runtime behaviors in modern concurrency as modern concurrency assumes all threads are always making forward progress. If you are planning to use this method only in contexts where you are not using modern concurrency, with Swift 5.7 you can provide attribute mark method unavailable in asynchronous context:

```swift
@available(*, noasync, message: "this method blocks thread use the async version instead")
func test(_ completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) -> Int {
    // do work that can block thread
}
```

By using this attribute you can only invoke this method from a non-async context. But some caution is needed as you can invoke non-async methods that call this method from an async context if that method doesn't specify `noasync` availability.

Comment: Don't use semaphores in conjunction with Swift Concurrency API. Never.

Comment: @vadian you can absolutely use semaphores in conjuction with concurrency API, you just have to take proper precautions. Read my updated answer on more details on how to do so.

Comment: A semaphore circumvents the async/await benefit to suspend threads. Apple strongly discourages to use semaphores. If you need Swift Concurrency in conjunction with completion handlers use `Continuation`s.

Comment: Better conversation is here in an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70962534/swift-await-async-how-to-wait-synchronously-for-an-async-task-to-complete), this answer is mostly a copy/paste from that but without the caveats.